# Adding keyup action to iframe of version of niceEdit

Tags: iframe, nicedit, keyup

I am using nicEdit in its iframe format.Everytime the user write anything in the editor(keyup event), I need to run another js/jquery function. How to add this custom keyup action to the desired iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer actually lies in the js code. In the nicEdit.js search for :

```
var nicEditorIFrameInstance = nicEditorInstance.extend({
```

Inside this, in the `initFrame` function,
look for `this.frameDoc.addEvent`.
This is where the events are being added(via addEvent). To this include your keyup statement :

```
addEvent('keyup',this.YOURFUNCTIONAME.closureListener(this))
```

You need to add `closureListener(this)` to get this working.Then create YOURFUNCTION after initFrame function like this :

```
YOURFUNCTIONAME: function() {
//Do what you like. Probably call any JS function that lies in the file where 
//you have included the nicEdit.js
},
```

This method worked for me. Hope it does for you too. nicEdit is by far the worst documented third party stuff I have ever come across.