# nicEdit : Add key(press|up|down) events to editor

Tags: javascript, nicedit

I'm using [nicEdit](http://nicedit.com) to have a RTF textarea and I need to add a `onkeypress`, `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` event.

I create my instance like this:

```
var emailRtf = new nicEditor({  iconsPath : 'nicEdit/nicEditorIcons.gif', 
    buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','fontSize','forecolor','ol','ul','link','unlink','removeformat'],
    maxHeight: 600}).panelInstance('REPLY_MESSAGE');
```

I tried the following (with `keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup`):

```
emailRtf.addEvent("keypress", function() { alert('test') }); // Not working
emailRtf.addEvent("keypress", function(evt) { alert('test') }); // Not working
```

However, the following works:

```
emailRtf.addEvent("blur", function() { alert('test') }); // Alert shows when I leave focus on the textArea
```

How can I add `key(press|up|down)` to a nicEdit editor?

**NOTE**: I have multiple instance of RTF textarea in my page and I need to add the `key(press|down|up)` event to only one. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163545/adding-keyup-action-to-iframe-of-version-of-niceedit) question, which add the event on all instances. **Also, I would like to leave nicEdit.js intact.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look
here [Limit the number of characters in a WYSIWYG Editor (NicEdit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159106/limit-the-number-of-characters-in-a-wysiwyg-editor-nicedit)

it should work without changes in nicedit.js

```
$("div.nicEdit-main").keyup(function () { });
```

Look at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/15/

Comment: Works! Without jQuery: `document.getElementById('REPLY_MESSAGE').parentElement.onkeypress = function () { alert('key pressed!'); };`

Comment: @SimonArsenault Thanks for the "without jquery" answer. This works perfectly and keeps NicEdit lightweight

Answer (score 3):

Read [the official documentation here](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/518/Editor%20Events). It shows you how to bind (their supported) events to your nicEdit instance *without using jQuery*:

```
var commentNicEditor = new nicEditor().panelInstance('comment');
commentNicEditor.addEvent("blur", function () {
    // Sent when an editor instance loses focus    
});
commentNicEditor.addEvent("focus", function () {
    // Send when an editor gains focus (IE someone clicks inside it)    
});
commentNicEditor.addEvent("key", function () {
    // When the user presses a shortcut key (Such as control-b)    
});
commentNicEditor.addEvent("add", function () {
    // Fired when a new instance is added    
});
commentNicEditor.addEvent("panel", function () {
    // Fired when the toolbar is initialized for new instances (This is the preferred event if you want to add a function when NicEdit instances are created)    
});
```

Comment: `commentNicEditor.addEvent("key", function () {
    // When the user presses a shortcut key (Such as control-b)    
});`

That's only for shortcut keys so it won't work.

Comment: @SimonArsenault it is in fact a piece of the official documentation on how to bind events without actually using `jQuery` since the question is not tagged with `jQuery`.

Comment: I know that, but if you read it it clearly says "shortcut keys (such as control-b)". It can not be used to capture every keys like onkeypress.  I believe the only way is the accepted answer (without jQuery is in the accepted's comments) or by directly modifying the code source (ugly way).

Answer (score 0):

After a day of research, I couldn't do it without modifying nicEdit.js. However, I was able to do with very few changes. Here they are (I am using version 0.9r24):

I added one config option named `customKeyDownFunction`. By default it does nothing.

```
var nicEditorConfig = bkClass.extend({
    buttons : {
        'bold' : {name : __('Click to Bold'), command : 'Bold', tags : ['B','STRONG'], css : {'font-weight' : 'bold'}, key : 'b'},
        'italic' : {name : __('Click to Italic'), command : 'Italic', tags : ['EM','I'], css : {'font-style' : 'italic'}, key : 'i'},
        'underline' : {name : __('Click to Underline'), command : 'Underline', tags : ['U'], css : {'text-decoration' : 'underline'}, key : 'u'},
        'left' : {name : __('Left Align'), command : 'justifyleft', noActive : true},
        'center' : {name : __('Center Align'), command : 'justifycenter', noActive : true},
        'right' : {name : __('Right Align'), command : 'justifyright', noActive : true},
        'justify' : {name : __('Justify Align'), command : 'justifyfull', noActive : true},
        'ol' : {name : __('Insert Ordered List'), command : 'insertorderedlist', tags : ['OL']},
        'ul' :  {name : __('Insert Unordered List'), command : 'insertunorderedlist', tags : ['UL']},
        'subscript' : {name : __('Click to Subscript'), command : 'subscript', tags : ['SUB']},
        'superscript' : {name : __('Click to Superscript'), command : 'superscript', tags : ['SUP']},
        'strikethrough' : {name : __('Click to Strike Through'), command : 'strikeThrough', css : {'text-decoration' : 'line-through'}},
        'removeformat' : {name : __('Remove Formatting'), command : 'removeformat', noActive : true},
        'indent' : {name : __('Indent Text'), command : 'indent', noActive : true},
        'outdent' : {name : __('Remove Indent'), command : 'outdent', noActive : true},
        'hr' : {name : __('Horizontal Rule'), command : 'insertHorizontalRule', noActive : true}
    },
    iconsPath : '../nicEditorIcons.gif',
    buttonList : ['save','bold','italic','underline','left','center','right','justify','ol','ul','fontSize','fontFamily','fontFormat','indent','outdent','image','upload','link','unlink','forecolor','bgcolor'],
    iconList : {"bgcolor":1,"forecolor":2,"bold":3,"center":4,"hr":5,"indent":6,"italic":7,"justify":8,"left":9,"ol":10,"outdent":11,"removeformat":12,"right":13,"save":24,"strikethrough":15,"subscript":16,"superscript":17,"ul":18,"underline":19,"image":20,"link":21,"unlink":22,"close":23,"arrow":25},
    customKeyDownFunction : function() { }  
});
```

I modified the keyDown function.

```
keyDown : function(e,t) {
    this.ne.options.customKeyDownFunction();

    if(e.ctrlKey) {
        this.ne.fireEvent('key',this,e);
    }
}
```

When I create my nicEditor instance, I define `customKeyDownFunction`.

```
var emailRtf = new nicEditor({  
        iconsPath : 'nicEdit/nicEditorIcons.gif', 
        buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','fontSize','forecolor','ol','ul','link','unlink','removeformat'],
        maxHeight: 600,
        customKeyDownFunction: function() { alert('key down!'); }
    }).panelInstance('REPLY_MESSAGE');
```

If you don't need any custom function, simply don't define `customKeyDownFunction`.

```
var emailRtf = new nicEditor({  
        iconsPath : 'nicEdit/nicEditorIcons.gif', 
        buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','fontSize','forecolor','ol','ul','link','unlink','removeformat'],
        maxHeight: 600
    }).panelInstance('REPLY_MESSAGE');
```

That's the best I could do. If someone has a better way, please tell!

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this way:

```
$('body').on("keyup", ".nicEdit-main", function(){
  //Do Something...
}
```